# How to structure typescript microservices repository on github

Tags: git, typescript, npm

I am working on designing an collection of microservices. I was using the following structure where each item is its own repository.

- `my-project-logger`
- `my-project-numbers-service` imports:

  - `my-project-logger` type definitions + class object (entire implementation)
  - `my-project-alphabet-service` type definitions
- `my-project-alphabet-service` imports:

  - `my-project-logger` type definitions + class object (entire implementation)
- `my-project-client` imports:

  - `my-project-logger` type definitions
  - `my-project-numbers-service` type definitions
  - `my-project-alphabet-service` type definitions

Then in my package.json I am saving all dependencies not required for the type definitions into devDependencies so they are not installed when the package is imported (only when cloned from git).

The problem comes when for example in the case of `my-project-logger` I only need the type definitions on the client but I need the entire implementation for the services. I'm not sure how to make the repository have two different install modes. One that installs only the type definitions and another that installs the entire implementation. Not being able to use npm (for publishing) also makes things a lot more difficult.

I have also tried using a monorepo approach with lerna but that makes deploying the microservices independently with docker extremely inefficient because you have to manually specifify each local dependecy in the dockerfile (since I can't use the npm website for publishing).

The last approach I tried was creating a `my-project-types` repository and having the types for every repository in there but that was annoying to develop on because every time you changed a type you had to re-pull the types repository for each service that depended on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right way to solve this is to publish multiple packages. You can publish a separate package just with type definitions.